# Getting the value of a dropdown menu using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added a little drop down menu to a webpage:

```
function addDropDownMenu() {
        var positionMenu = $(
            "<form class='drop_down_menu'>" +
                "<select name='roles'>" +
                    "<option value='notSelected'>Not Selected</option>"+
                    "<option value='relevant'>Relevant</option>"+
                    "<option value='notRelevant'>Not Relevant</option>" + 
                "</select>" +
            "</form>");

        $('#profile-experience .position').prepend(positionMenu)
    }
```

I am trying to get the value of either `Relevant` or `Not Relevant`.

However, when I run this code I keep getting an empty string.

```
var x = $('.drop_down_menu')[0]
// x is the form
$(x).val()
```

returns `""`

What am I missing? Doing wrong?

Comment: You need `$('.drop_down_menu select').val()`

Comment: @Morgan, it is working for you ?

Comment: took me a while to figure out what was happening. For some reason the debugger was focusing on an iFrame and thus why it kept returning empty. All of these answers worked :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
var selectedValue = $('.drop_down_menu>select').val();
```

```js
var selectedValue = $('.drop_down_menu>select').val();
console.log('The selected value is: '+ selectedValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class='drop_down_menu'>
  <select name='roles'>
  <option value='notSelected'>Not Selected</option>
  <option value='relevant' selected>Relevant</option>
  <option value='notRelevant'>Not Relevant</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.drop_down_menu')` statement returns a **jquery** element with the properties and methods corresponding to it, but `$('.drop_down_menu')[0]` just returns the `HTML` **DOM** element.

You have to use `value` property in order to obtain the `value` of select element.

```js
console.log($('select')[0].value);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='roles'>
  <option value='notSelected'>Not Selected</option>
  <option value='relevant' selected>Relevant</option>
  <option value='notRelevant'>Not Relevant</option>
  </select>
```

Your example does not work because you have to use a **selector** for select element

```js
var x = $('.drop_down_menu > select')[0]
console.log($(x).val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class='drop_down_menu'>
          <select name='roles'>
              <option value='notSelected'>Not Selected</option>
              <option value='relevant' selected>Relevant</option>
              <option value='notRelevant'>Not Relevant</option> 
          </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Please explain your downvote...Why some people downvotes correct answers ?

Comment: what does the `> select` do?

Comment: this get the `direct` descendent of form element which is select

Comment: you could also use `children` method.. $('.drop_down_menu').children('select')

Answer (score 0):

```
var _val = $("[name='roles']").val();
console.log(_val);
```

Comment: you need : Getting the value of a dropdown menu using jQuery.

Comment: While answers are always appreciated, it really helps to provide some additional info regarding **how** your code solves the problem at hand. Doing so aids those with similar (but not identical) problems. Not everyone may be familiar with your exact coding logic, but may understand your general *approach* or *concept*. To help improve your answer, please provide some [**context surrounding it**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762), and see the help article on [**writing great answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips on how to make your answers count :)